# convert m3u FILE to m3u8 URL

Tags: m3u8, m3u

hello I JUST NEED SMOE HOW CONVERT M3U TO M3U8 URL I HAD TRYING ALL THE WAY THAT I KNOW
BUT I STILL GITTING ISSUES SO HOW CAN I CONVER M3U FILE TO M3U8 URL

THANK YOU

I HAD TRY TO USE NOTEPED++ BUT I STILL GITTING ISSUE I DONT HOW I JUST WANNA CONVERT M3U TO M3U8 URL

THANK YOU